# Reverse words with more than 4 characters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to see why my function keeps returning undefined?

The output should be the same string but with every word with over 4 characters reversed?

Sorry I'm still a noob with JavaScript and this is driving me crazy lol

Thank you!

```
const reverseString = (data) => {
    data = data.split(' '); //convert to array
    data = data.forEach(function flipper (x) {
        x = x.split('');
        if (x.length > 4) {
            x = x.reverse();
        }
        x = x.join('');
    });
    return console.log(data);
}

reverseString('Hello World thank you so much');
```

Comment: See function > don't see any `return` > ??? > `undefined`

Comment: Your `forEach` function doesn't actually change anything in `data`. Try changing to `data.map` and replace `x = x.join('');` with `return x.join('');`

Comment: Oh you're definitely right let me add that now! Will update the main thread in a minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all forEach returns `undefined` so you cann't assing directly to source array.
As you need to assign the reverse string to source array. It would be better to use third parameter(i.e source array) of callback function in forEach

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const reverseString = (data) => {
  data = data.split(" "); //convert to array
  data.forEach(function flipper(x, i, src) {
    x = x.split("");
    if (x.length > 4) {
      x = x.reverse();
    }
    x = x.join("");
    src[i] = x;
  });
  return data.join(" ");
};

const result = reverseString("Hello World thank you so much");
console.log(result);
```

It is easy to achieve this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const reverseString = (data) => {
  return data
    .split(" ")
    .map(x => x.length > 4 ? x.split("").reverse().join("") : x)
    .join(" ");
};

const result = reverseString("Hello World thank you so much");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Man how do you get so good at this? That was so perfect. Any resource you would recommend to improve my JavaScript skills?

Comment: Practice brother, There is nothing secret. Just go step by step. Pick one topic solve some of its problems, mainly the one that seems hard. Because those are the ones that teach you how to think. Read other's code and think about why he/she has done this. Hope it helps 

Comment: Thank you @decpk ! I'm having trouble understanding the x => x.length part? is that an es6 function? I thought it would have to be written .map((x) => {....});?

Comment: that's ES6 arrow function. It is just new way to define function with shorter syntax with some other benifits. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you assign the returned value from forEach() to the data variable.

the function forEach returns nothing but `undefined`

Check the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You may use the map function in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, your function can be re-written as follows:

```js
const reverseString = 
  data => data
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => word.length > 4 ? word.split("").reverse().join("") : word)
    .join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with a regex in `replace()` with  a replacement callback

```js
const reverseString = str => str.replace(/\S{5,}/gi, (s) => [...s].reverse().join(''))

const str ='Hello World thank you so much';
console.log(reverseString(str))
```